# sql muliple scenario using if condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have column email and for some ids there are multiple .

```
email
adi@gmail.com
lim@yy.com lim@ey.com
kim@ec.com kim@ef.com ki@yy.com
```

my requirement is to get only the first id

Myquery:

```
select SUBSTRING(email, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', email)) AS [First]
from aditya_dbprofile
```

this is working but where there is single email it is giving blank.

Help!!

Comment: Forcibly add a blank space at the end of the string being searched, to ensure it has something to find...  `CHARINDEX(' ', email + ' ')`

Comment: If you are interested in separate emails, you shouldn't store them concatenated, but in separate columns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On possible solution is to add space after the `email` value and use `LEFT()` or `SUBSTRING()`:

```
SELECT LEFT(email, CHARINDEX(' ', CONCAT(email, ' '))) AS [First]
FROM aditya_dbprofile

-- or

SELECT SUBSTRING(email, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', CONCAT(email, ' '))) AS [First]
FROM aditya_dbprofile
```